# What is the significance of the order of statements in mysql explain output?

Tags: mysql, sql-execution-plan

This is mysql explain plan for one of the query I am looking into.

```
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table2 | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    6 |       | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table3 | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |   23 |       | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table1 | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |    8 |       | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table5 | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    1 |       | 
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+
```

4 rows in set (0 sec)

What is the significance of the order of statements in this output ?
Does it mean that table5 is read before all others ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tables are listed in the output in the order that MySQL would read them while processing the query.  You can [read more about the Explain plan output here](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/MySQL-Optimization-part-1/2/).

Additionally, the output tells me:

- The optimizer saw the query as having four (4) SELECT statements within it.  Being a "simple" select type, those queries are not using UNION  or subqueries.
- Two of those statements could use indexes (based on the `type` column), which were primary keys (based on the `key` column).  The other two could not use any indexes.